# How will I validate the mobile number in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const mobileNoSchema = mongoose.Schema(
mobileNo: {
            type: String,
            // min: [10, "no is < 10"],
            // max: [10, "no is > 10"],
            validate: {
                validator: function(v) {
                    if(v.length === 10) return true;
                    return /\d{10}/.test(v);
                },
                message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
            }   
        }
);

const Mobile= mongoose.model("mobile", mobileNoSchema);
export default Mobile;
```

My code is not working if i try using `min` and `max` validating only for max value
can anybody help me out

Comment: What is the value that you are trying to insert?

Comment: If I insert this no 987654321 it gives me validation error of "no > 10" and even if i insert "987654321012" then also it gives me validation error of "no > 10", but I only wan 10 digit no to be inserted not more or less than it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` are validators for type `Number`. They are used to compare Number values, not the lengths of the strings. If you want to compare lengths, use `minLength` and `maxLength` validators. Also, if you need to check whether all characters are numbers use `match` validator like this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const mobileNoSchema = mongoose.Schema(
mobileNo: {
            type: String,
            minLength: [10, "no should have minimum 10 digits"],
            maxLength: [10, "no should have maximum 10 digits"],
            match: [/\d{10}/, "no should only have digits"]
);
const Mobile= mongoose.model("mobile", mobileNoSchema);
export default Mobile;
```

[Documentation link.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this condition below:

```js
const yourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  phoneNr: {
    type: String,
    match: /^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/,
  }
});
```

Comment: yes... trying with this also

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.